# Select with random ORDER in MySQL Within 1 row

Tags: mysql, random, sql-order-by

I Have this `Level 1` table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2pOa.png)
I want to make query, when the query is execute the order of J1,J2.. J5 is in random order

I have this query

```
SELECT j1,j2,j3,j4,j5 FROM `level_1` ORDER BY RAND()
```

but it only randomize the index row, not the inside
[image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMsGv.png)

I want to make this result with random column order, but cant figure it out yet
[I hope this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvvij.png)

Comment: The column headings are meaningless in the output since they don't inform what the column data means..do you care?

Comment: you're right. I need another solution and I find it. I just wanna make random multiple choice, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling this should be a duplicate but can't find one so..unpivot using union all , allocate a random row number then aggregate

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, J1 INT,J2 INT,J3 INT,J4 INT,J5 INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1,1,2,3,4,5),(2,10,20,30,40,50);
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ID,1 AS COL, J1 FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,2 AS COL, J2 FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,3 AS COL, J3 FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,4 AS COL, J4 FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,5 AS COL, J5 FROM T
),
CTE1 AS
(SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RAND()) RN FROM CTE)
SELECT ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN J1 END) COL1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN J1 END) COL2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN J1 END) COL3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN J1 END) COL4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 5 THEN J1 END) COL5
FROM CTE1 
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/kRMABZp7

Comment: I dont event know mysql cam do that, thank you very much